# How do you prove the trigonometric identity $(\sin a - \sin b + 1)^2 = (\sin a + \sin b)^2 + \cos^2a\cos^2b$?

Tags: trigonometry

We just started to learn trigonometry. So far, we have learned
\begin{align*}
\sin^2 a + \cos^2 a & = 1\\
\tan a & = \frac{\sin a}{\cos a}
\end{align*}

How can I prove this identity?

$$(\sin a - \sin b + 1)^2 = (\sin a + \sin b)^2 + \cos^2 a\cos^2 b$$

Comment: $\sin(a) +\cos(a)  \neq 1 $. Though it is true for some $a$. I think you mean$\sin^2 (a) +\cos^2 (a) =1 $

Comment: I'm not sure if it is cos^2a*cos^2b or cos^2a-cos^2b

Comment: Have you tried expanding the squares and cancelling stuff out?

Comment: yes I tried that

Comment: Your "identity" is not always true. See my answer.

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that
$(\sin a - \sin b + 1)^2 = (\sin a + \sin b)^2 + \cos^2 a\cos^2 b$.

The left side is

$\begin{array}\\
(\sin a - \sin b + 1)^2
&=\sin^2 a + \sin^2 b + 1 -2\sin a \sin b + 2\sin a - 2 \sin b\\
&=\sin^2 a + \sin^2 b +2\sin a \sin b+1-4\sin a \sin b + 2\sin a - 2 \sin b\\
&=(\sin a + \sin b)^2-4\sin a \sin b + 2\sin a - 2 \sin b+1\\
&=(\sin a + \sin b)^2-(4\sin a \sin b - 2\sin a + 2 \sin b-1)\\
&=(\sin a + \sin b)^2-(2\sin a + 1)(2\sin b - 1)\\
\end{array}
$

This is starting to look
like your "identity"
might not be true.

Suppose $a = b$.
It becomes

$\begin{array}\\
1
&=(2\sin a)^2+\cos^4 a\\
&=4\sin^2 a+\cos^4 a\\
&=4(1-\cos^2 a)+\cos^4 a\\
&=4-4\cos^2 a+\cos^4 a\\
&= (2-\cos^2 a)^2\\
\end{array}
$

Since $\cos^2 a \le 1$,
this is true only if
$1 = 2-\cos^2 a$
or
$\cos^2 a = 1$.

Therefore your "identity"
is not always true.

Continuing from my expansion,
your "identity" holds
only when

$-(2\sin a + 1)(2\sin b - 1)
=\cos^2 a\cos^2 b
=(1-\sin^2 a)(1-\sin^2 b)
$
or
$\frac{2\sin a + 1}{1-\sin^2 a}
=-\frac{1-\sin^2 b}{2\sin b - 1}
=\frac{1-\sin^2 b}{1-2\sin b }
$.
Letting $c = -b$,
this becomes
$\frac{2\sin a + 1}{1-\sin^2 a}
=\frac{1-\sin^2 c}{1+2\sin c }
$.

Letting
$f(x)
=\frac{2\sin x + 1}{1-\sin^2 x}
$,
this is
$f(a) = 1/f(-b)$.
Therefore,
for any $a$,
$b$ is pretty well determined
(modulo $2\pi$).

To find the inverse of $f$,
we want to solve
$y 
=\frac{2\sin x + 1}{1-\sin^2 x}
$
for $\sin x$.

This becomes
$y(1-\sin^2 x)=2\sin x + 1$.
Letting $z = \sin x$,
this is
$y-yz^2
=2z+1
$
or
$yz^2+2z+1-y = 0$.

From the quadratic formula
$z
=\frac{-2\pm \sqrt{4-4y(1-y)}}{2y}
=\frac{-2\pm \sqrt{4-4y(1-y)}}{2y}
=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{1-y+y^2}}{y}
$.

I'll leave it at this.